# Hover присваивается к каждому элементу

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с проблемой: Hover присваивается к каждому элементу в таблице, а по начальным данным должен работать на каждой ячейке при наведении мыши. Пробывал множество способов расстановки li, ul и элементов классов. Ничего не помогает. В чем я ошибся?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#teamgrouplist li:hover .selizionaton_in_table,
#teamlist li:hover .selizionaton_in_table {
  display: block;
}

#teamgrouplist li:hover a,
#teamlist li:hover a {
  background-color: #00244D !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_content">
  <ul class="sidebar__menu sidebar__menu--left  ">
    <li class="menu-item open scroll" style="max-height: calc(100% - 45px);">
      <ul id="teamgrouplist" class="submenu">
        <li v-for="(t, index) in teams" style="border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;">
          <div style="width: 100%; position: relative">
            <a :id="[['team_'+t.tid]]" @click="getGroups(t)" :class="{pointer: true, groupExpanded: t.showGroups}" class="linknameteam" style="-webkit-box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none;padding-left: 10px;margin-right: 0px; font-size: 9pt;"
              :title="[[t.team_name]]">[[t.team_name | truncate(20,'...')]]
            </a>
          </div>
          <div v-if="t.team_name == selectedTeam" v-for="(g, index2) in t.groups" style="width: 100%; position: relative;">
            <a :id="[['team_group_'+g.gid]]" class="pointer tgitem" @click="getContacts_for_Groups(g)" style="x-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none; margin-right: 0px;font-size: 9pt;background: #00254c;" :title="[[g.group_name]]">
                             [[g.list_name | truncate(20,'...')]]
               </a>
            <div style="position: absolute; right: 5px; top: 5px; width: 30px; height: 30px;overflow: hidden; padding:0px;" class="selizionaton_in_table">

              <a class="remove_item" @click="deleteGroup(g.gid, index2)" style="margin-top:3px; cursor: pointer; -webkit-box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none; margin-right: 0px; padding: 5px;" alt="Elimina lista" title="Elimina lista">
                <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: не понятно, как и что надо....

Comment: @Air при наведении мыши показываются все элементы hover'a , то есть значок минус с права. Пытаюсь сделать что бы был значок справа при наведении только на одну ячейку, и отображался он только в ней. Сейчас когда наводишь мышь на любую ячейку, символ минуса отображается на всех ячейках сразу. А изначально требовалось только что бы на конкретной.

Comment: сделай минимальный самодостаточный воспроизводимый пример... я там значек минуса не вижу

Comment: Ошибка в селекторе который выбирает div с классом selizionaton_in_table. Точнее этот селектор выбирает все div. Попробуйте так - #teamgrouplist li:hover > .selizionaton_in_table

Comment: @Air значек минуса это Font Awesome, в коде указан как (<i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>)

Comment: @TolikAli попробывал, теперь вообще пропал знак минуса :D

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему которая заключалась в CSS стиле.
Переписал и hover заработал именно на конкретном элементе:

```
#teamgrouplist  li:hover .selizionaton_in_table, #teamlist div:hover .selizionaton_in_table{ display: block; }
```